# AngularJS link not existing in the config

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For the project that I am currently developing, I am using AngularJS 1.5 and ui-router.

There is a module which is under subdirectory and it is not part of the main web site.

From homepage of the web site we have link that leads to this module.

The problem is that when I click on the link, web site is not reloading and link is searched as a state in the config. Is there any option that I can set in the html which will tell that the page should be reload.

Comment: Yes.  Use `templateUrl` in the routeConfig.